# Is it possible to set the default machine-type and default image for Google Cloud gcloud tool?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have installed and configured Google Cloud SDK. It works fine but the invocation commands tend to get a bit long.

Is it possible to set the default machine-type and default image to use like you can with default zone and region?

```
$ gcloud config list  
[compute]
region = europe-west1
zone = europe-west1-c
```

In particular, I'd like to use Canonical's Ubuntu 14.10 image and n1-standard-2 instead of

```
--machine-type MACHINE_TYPE; default="n1-standard-1"
                       Specifies the machine type used for the instances.
```

Or do I need to do something ugly like an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images and type machines aren't part of the compute properties. If you do run the command  `gcloud config list --all`, you can see the properties that you can set.